# WLAN Transfer never over 2MB/s

Tags: internet

I have a Phone and a Router with WLAN n-Technology, but i never get more Speed than 2MB/s (Only in Speedtests, not from Computer to Phone) I tried SSH, FTP and MyPhoneExplorer.

Any Ideas what i could do / check?

Answer (score 1):

The speed is limited by weakest point in the system. If you are using a class 2 microSD, you can't get speed more than 2MBps even if your network can transfer 1TBps.

Comment: Any way to Bench the SD-Card?

Comment: @Styler2go: You can try [SD Tools](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ales.veluscek.sdtools&hl=en).

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure that your router is in n-only mode, since if there's even one g-mode device in the access point, the speed gets dropped from all devices, except if the device has separate chips for g-mode and n-mode.

Also, your devices CPU and RAM can cause limitations. For example, my Galaxy Nexus can handle speeds up to 30MBps whereas the original Galaxy capped at about 10MBps despite being attached to a 100MBps access point.